# Tensorflow input pipeline for Keras (TFRecords)

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, keras, pipeline

I built an input pipeline for Tensorflow to read my data. It is encoded into TFRecord files. I would like to use QueueRunners to prefetch the data and give it as an input to a Keras model.

Something along these lines:

```
image_batch, label_batch = MayTFRecordsPipeline.get_batch()
#Keras
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(tensor=image_batch))
```

How would that work with QueueRunners?
Internally, the pipeline uses (simplified)

```
def get_batch():
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(self.tfrecord_file_path_list)
    tf_keys, decoded_fs = self.decode_multiple_tfrecord(filename_queue)
    tensor_list = self.get_multiple_example(decoded_fs)                                            
    imageBatch, labelBatch= self.create_joined_shuffled_data_batch(tensor_list)
    return image_batch, label_batch
```

Comment: if you found an answer somewhere else, consider adding it here :)